# No thumbnail in Product List (OroCommerce)

Tags: orocrm, orocommerce

I've even run message consumer, but no luck.
[image: orocommerce product list]

How to get thumbnail in product list?

Answer (score 1):

You can generate image thumbnail using the console command:

```sh
php bin/console product:image:resize-all
```

Comment: It works - at least it adds a message to the queue.
But when it processed by ImageResizeMessageProcessor and pass ProductImage to ProductImagesDimensionsProvider, which returns empty $dimensions array. Because $productImage->getTypes() is also empty. So, as a result no thumbnails generated.
Why?

Comment: Dimensions are defined in theme.yml. https://doc.oroinc.com/frontend/storefront/images/#image-resizing-and-watermarks.
Make sure they are defined in any of the enabled themes. And make sure all product images belong to some image type. You can check it in a product edit page (by default there are main, listing and additional image types, at least one of them must be checked for any image).

Comment: Actually it's not about layout. This image in datagrid and I found in `OroProductBundle:Product:Datagrid/image.html.twig` that it should be `product_small`. There should be some default options for this image size config, isn't it?

Comment: Yea, here it is - vendor/oro/commerce/src/Oro/Bundle/ProductBundle/Resources/views/layouts/default/config/images.yml Now I need to find out why it's not loaded...

Comment: So finally I got my image back. Somehow oro_product_image_type was empty for my image. I've reload image and it works. Thanks a lot for your support! You are the best!

Answer (score 0):

The fix for me was to edit the Product, and then edit the image and assign a "type" to the image by checking the "Main" radio button. This seems to trigger the logic that builds the thumbnail image for the Product list page (in admin), and *also* for the storefront image.
If you add another image and select the "Listing" radio button then *that* image will be used instead of the "Main" image for "listing" purposes.
Be sure that your message queue consumer is running.